# How to Determine EndPoint and Current Model When Using Loopback's New Operational Hooks?

Tags: rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

When using the new L[oopback Operational Hooks](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks#Operationhooks-beforesave) how can we determine which endpoint triggered the hook in cases where the instance is not passed? For example, using 'before save' how do we know which endpoint and model we're dealing with?

```
        model.observe('before save', function updateTimestamp(ctx, next) {

            if (ctx.instance) {
                ctx.instance.updated = new Date();
            } else {
                // HOW TO DETERMINE ENDPOINT AND MODEL HERE?    
                ctx.data.updated = new Date();
            }

            next();

        });
```